# Android How to achieve different layout for screens in the same size bucket?

Tags: android, android-screen-support, android-screen

I noticed that the normal size bucket is quite big. My app works great on my own 4.3" but on a smaller phone in the normal range it looks weird or does not fit.

How do you solve this?

I find the whole layout strategy a bit broken. I know you should not calculate things from screensize but if that functionality was reliable then calculating things in percentages would be easier to use.

Now you have to design something for screens that are to different in size.

Answer (score 0):

> How do you solve this?

Use `-swNNNdp`, `-wNNNdp`, and/or `-hNNNdp`, to set your own divisions for where the changes should occur (where NNN is a number of density-independent pixels).

These have been around since 2011 and are covered in many places in the documentation, such as [the Best Practices area](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: But that is API 11, I want to support api 8 if i can.

Comment: @user2257389: Actually, they are API Level 13, IIRC. You will need to design a more flexible UI that can handle all screen sizes in the `-normal` bucket.

Comment: So should I combine -swNNNdp with supports-screens? But then I need to make sure I have swNNNdp for the smallest phones in the ranges i support or else what happens. User installs app because he has a normal bucket phone but if there is no swNNNdp for that phone it will crash?

Comment: @user2257389: "User installs app because he has a normal bucket phone but if there is no swNNNdp for that phone it will crash?" -- always have one of *every* layout in `res/layout/`. Override those layouts as needed in other directories like `res/layout-swNNNdp/`. That ensures that every device will be able to load something.

Comment: How do i account for orientation changes when using the smallest width qualifier?